# Determining if $\mathbb{Z}[a]$ is a discrete subring of $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integer-lattices

Let $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}[a]$. Is there some nice criterion which will tell me whether $\mathbb{Z}[a]$ is discrete in the sense that there is some $\delta >0$ such that, whenever $x \in \mathbb{Z}[a] \setminus \{0\}$, one has $|x| \geq  \delta$?  It follows, then, that there is a smallest possible distance between any two points.

I have been able to show some pretty easy things, such as:

> **Fact 1**: A subring $R \subset \mathbb{C}$ is discrete if and only if $\{ |x| : x \in R\} \subset [0,\infty)$ is order isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$.
>
> **Fact 2:** The only discrete (unital) subring of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Fact 2 makes the case $a \in \mathbb{R}$ pretty easy: we get $\mathbb{Z}[a]$ discrete if and only if $a \in \mathbb{Z}$.

The case where $a \in \mathbb{C}$ is pure imaginary is also pretty easy. You need $\mathbb{Z}[a^2] \subset \mathbb{Z}[a]$ to be discrete, so you need $a^2$ an integer, i.e. $a = \pm \sqrt{n}i$ for some positive integer $n$.  It's not hard to show that, for such $a$, the ring $\mathbb{Z}[a]$ is also discrete.

The next case I tried was the case where $a$ is a root of unity. If $a \neq 1$ is a third root of unity, things work out quite nicely: it turns out that $\mathbb{Z}[a]$ is a hexagonal lattice.

However, if $a \neq 1$ is a  fifth root of unity, it gets difficult to compute by bare hands, and I am not too sure what happens.

Comment: It is an interesting exercise to show that any additive subgroup of the set off real numbers is either discrete or dense. (Kronecker?) This s elementary real analysis and relevant to your question.

Comment: @PVanchinathan: I knew that already, but thanks just the same. Incidentally, the "Fact 1" I wrote above is also an exercise in elementary real analysis.

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathbb Z[a]$ is a discret, then $\mathbb Z$-module $\mathbb Z[a]$ finitely generated, hence $a$ must be an [algebraic integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer) number. If $n$ is a degree of a [minimal polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(field_theory)) of $a$, then $\mathbb Z$-module $\mathbb Z[a]$ generated by $1,a,\ldots,a^{n-1}$ and they generate a discret subgroup of $\mathbb C^+$ ($\mathbb C$ by addition). Conversely, let $a$ be an algebraic integer of degree $n$ such, that $1,a,\ldots,a^{n-1}$ generate a discret subgroup of $\mathbb C^+$. Then $\mathbb Z[a]$ as a subfgroup of $\mathbb C^+$ is generated by $1,a,\ldots,a^{n-1}$, so, by assumption, $\mathbb Z[a]$ is a discret subgroup in $\mathbb C^+$.

It remains to understand in which cases $1,a,\ldots,a^{n-1}$ generate a discret subgroup of a $\mathbb C^+$. Besides that, should be considered, that $1,a,\ldots,a^{n-1}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$, and any discret subgroup in $\mathbb C^+$ has rank not greater 2, so $n\leq 2$. If $n=1$, then $a\in\mathbb Z$. Let $n=2$. If $a\not\in\mathbb R$, then $1,a$ generate over $\mathbb Z$ discret subgroup. If $a\in\mathbb R$, then $1,a$ generate discret subgroup of a $\mathbb R^+$ iff $\{1,a\}\subset t\mathbb Z$ for some $0\neq t\in\mathbb R$. Hence $1=ty$, $a=tx$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb Z$. Then $a=\frac{a}{1}=\frac{tx}{ty}=\frac{x}{y}\in\mathbb Q$ - contradiction, since $a$ has degree 2 over $\mathbb Q$.

In such a way, we get the answer: $\mathbb Z[a]$ is a discret subgroup in $\mathbb C^+$ iff $a\in\mathbb Z$ or $a$ is a nonreal quadratic algebraic integer (i.e. $a$ is a root of a polynomial $x^2+ux+v$, where $u,v\in\mathbb Z$ and discriminant is negative).

Comment: Nothing wrong with the math, but a moderator's advice: editing for the reason of improving the post is, of course, fine. But because an edit "bumps" the post to the front page it can also be abused as an attention seeking tool. There's no evidence of that here, but at some point you may begin to attract negative attention. If you sense a need for lot of edits, you can use [the sandbox](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts) which was created for such a purpose.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for your advice.